# Яндекс Карты API 429 Too Many Requests

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, карты

Буквально пару дней назад появилась проблема с доступом к картам на собственном сайте. Запросов до 100 в день, а ответ отдает- `429 Too Many Requests`.
С чем может быть связана проблема? Пытался связаться с ТП Яндекса, никто не отвечает

Comment: Значит все заняты разбором этой траблы. Видимо Вы не первый кто им написал об этом. Если Ваш сайт не ломали и Вы ничего не меняли - значит что-то у янда случилось.

Comment: Такая же история. И тоже началось пару дней назад.

Answer (score 1):

Это значит, что в запросах к API вы не передаете API-ключ.

В октябре прошлого года в API Яндекс.Карт изменились правила доступа: теперь при подключении JS API и в запросах к HTTP API Геокодера нужно передавать ключ.

Раньше ключ был только в платной версии, а теперь он нужен и для работы с бесплатной. Если вы используете JS API или HTTP Геокодер, пожалуйста, получите ключ и обновите ваш проект. API Карт будет работать корректно только с сервисами, которые передают ключ.

Получить ключ можно в Кабинете разработчика: developer.tech.yandex.ru . Там же вы сможете следить за статистикой и контролировать, не приближается ли количество запросов к лимиту.

Подробную информацию о получении ключа и подключении API вы можете найти здесь:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/quick-start/index-docpage/